# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: plugins, headers

I am getting this error, when I am doing

`example.com/wp-admin`

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mytheme/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:1) in /home/mytheme/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 899

some code here

```
<?php
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 604;

/**
 * Add support for a custom header image.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Twenty Thirteen only works in WordPress 3.6 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.6-alpha', '<' ) )
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';

/**
 * Twenty Thirteen setup.
 *
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers the various WordPress features that
 * Twenty Thirteen supports.
 *
 * @uses load_theme_textdomain() For translation/localization support.
 * @uses add_editor_style() To add Visual Editor stylesheets.
 * @uses add_theme_support() To add support for automatic feed links, post
 * formats, and post thumbnails.
 * @uses register_nav_menu() To add support for a navigation menu.
 * @uses set_post_thumbnail_size() To set a custom post thumbnail size.
 *
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
```

Any idea. Also i checked there is no empty space around

Comment: Paste first 20 lines of codes from `functions.php`

Comment: @Roberthue : i added the code

Answer (score 0):

There is a [FAQ Troubleshooting](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting) entry [How do I solve the *Headers already sent warning* problem?](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F) dedicated to this. You should check your `wp-config.php`, because there might possibly be some white-spaces - spaces, new lines or so - causing the message. Although the message you posted indicates the problem lies in line 1 of you `functions.php`. Redirects are a typical candidate for the *Headers already sent warning* too.